JSON conversion error from aws configservice query
I have a problem generating the list of my resources in AWS, and later converting them into CSV using the JQ command, exactly this is the command I am running from the AWS CLI
aws configservice select-resource-config --expression "
SELECT
  accountId,
  awsRegion,
  resourceType,
  configuration.instanceType,
  configuration.dBInstanceClass,
  arn,
  configuration.description,
  configuration.role,
  configuration.volumeType,
  configuration.size,
  configuration.platform,
  configuration.engineVersion,
  configuration.architecture,
  configuration.runtime,
  configuration.vpcId,
  configuration.subnetId,
  configuration.dNSName,
  configuration.publicIpAddress,
  configuration.publicDnsName,
  configuration.privateIpAddress,
  configuration.privateDnsName,
  configuration.securityGroups,
  configuration.status
" --output json |  \
jq -r '["ID Cuenta", "Region AWS", "Tipo Recurso", "Tipo Instancia EC2", "Tipo DB RDS", "ARN", "Descipcion", "Rol", "Tipo Volumen", "Tamaño", "Plataforma", "Engine Version", "Arquitectura", "Runtime", "VPC", "Subnet ID", "DNS", "IP Pública", "DNS Público", "IP Privada", "DNS Privado", "Security Groups", "Estado"], (.Results[] | fromjson | [.accountId, .awsRegion, .resourceType, .configuration.instanceType, .configuration.dBInstanceClass, .arn, .configuration.description, .configuration.role, .configuration.volumeType, .configuration.size, .configuration.platform, .configuration.engineVersion, .configuration.architecture, .configuration.runtime, .configuration.vpcId, .configuration.subnetId, .configuration.dNSName, .configuration.publicIpAddress, .configuration.publicDnsName, .configuration.privateIpAddress, .configuration.privateDnsName, .configuration.securityGroups, .configuration.status]) | @csv' > data.csv &&
iconv -f UTF-8 data.csv -o data.csv

The export command works correctly, but the problem occurs when converting from JSON to CSV, and it occurs only with some AWS accounts or resources, an error is generated in the conversion and the CSV generation process fails and stops , this is the output in the shell
Bus error (core dumped)

or
jq: error (at <stdin>:623): array ([{"value":"...) is not valid in a csv row

In this last case in particular, the conversion process with the JQ command was stopped, checking the first export was generated correctly and the line where the exception was generated contains this (comparing CSV file with JSON file), line not processed (not appears in CSV file):
"{\"accountId\":\"ID_ACCOUNT\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-east-1\",\"configuration\":{\"vpcId\":\"vpc-XXXXXX_ID\",\"securityGroups\":[{\"value\":\"sg-XXXXX_ID\"},{\"value\":\"sg-YYYY_UD\"}],\"dNSName\":\"awseb-AWSEB-XXXXXXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com\"},\"arn\":\"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXX_ID:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-XXXXXXX/YYYYY\",\"resourceType\":\"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer\"}",

The question is, how could I fix this so that JQ processes the line generated by AWS configservice
Or alternatively, how could I skip this line to avoid and continue processing the file (I have more than 50 AWS accounts and doing it manually continuously is not optional)
Referral documentation: https://repost.aws/es/articles/ARQz1QqJx0R7ioSz3nI3noeg/returning-aws-config-aggregator-results-as-csv

For more insight, please provide (an excerpt of) the output of the aws command (top-level included), before it is piped into jq. Based on your (probably incomplete) snippet, which looks like a stream of JSON-encoded strings containing JSON-encoded objects, I'd remove .Results[] from before fromjson.

Hello @pmf i Try remove .Results[] | 
The new error:  jq: error (at <stdin>:623): object ({"Results":...) only strings can be parsed

Then provide the JSON output as asked. Without it, this is just guessing.

The output of the JSON initially generated by configservice is generated completely, the problem occurs when running the JQ command (it only happens with some AWS accounts)
My question is, is there a way to force JQ to process the file even if there are errors, or better, skip the lines and continue processing the file and skip the lines with errors, or do you know any other method to convert the JSON file? to CSV so that the AWS item inventory is easily understandable in a spreadsheet?

jq doesn't "skip lines". It reads the entire input (typically a JSON entity), and processes it according to your filters. That's why I was asking for the output including the top-level part. Once you show (a sample of) a full output which includes the regular structure and the faulty one, we can help you adapt your filter to deal with both cases.

Hello @pmf
This is the output of the JSON: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BkNpVFssrg/
In the latest line, crash process

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
